# how can i use my html tags inside controllers functions

Tags: php, html, laravel

**here is my laravel html**

```
    <!-- end left -->
    <div class="right">
        <--call function-->
        <?php
            use App\Http\Controllers\CVController;
            echo CVController::functionName();
        ?>

        <div class="right-container">
           @if(count($form_data['oc_experiences'])>count($form_data['oc_formations']))
            <hr>
            <!-- test experience -->
            <hr>
      @endif
        </div>

    </div>
```

I called the function .. it work . 
but i don't know how can i use html in my controller

**here is my controller**

```
 <?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use DB;
    use App;
    use Cache;
    use Session;
    use Exception;
    use App\Http\Controllers\CommonController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\PermController;
    use App\Http\Controllers\CVController;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

    class CVController extends Controller
    {
        use CommonController;
        use PermController;

        //my function that i would like to use 
        public static function functionName()
        {
            //how can i use my html tags here ????
        }
    }
```

how can i use my html tags inside controllers functions
help please

Comment: what is your purpose to use HTML in the controller?

Comment: i just wanna test some loops Laravel in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example with ECHO

```
 public static function functionName()
        {
          echo '<p>Hello</p>';  //how can i use my html tags here ????
        }
```

Comment: @Hamza why stop acept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Why use HTML in the controller?

just create a blade file in laravel views folder.
as. **filename.blade.php**
and in your controller method write this only to call your view or blade.

```
public function methodName(){
   return view('filename');
}
```

Try this.